# css insert image inside linear-gradient half part

Tags: html, css

I have a css background animation that separate the screen into 2 color part, div 1 left is black and div 2 right is white. However I want to make the div 2 right white part to become a image background while black part remain.

How do I insert the image cover into the right white part without affect the left black part

this is the example image cover I would like to cover in div 2

[image]

below is my code

```css
body,
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.bg {
    min-height: 100vh;
    animation: BgAnimation;
    -webkit-animation: BgAnimation;
    -moz-animation: BgAnimation;
    background: linear-gradient(106deg, #313131 50%, white 50.1%);
    animation-duration: 1.3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    background-size: 200% 200%;
}

@keyframes BgAnimation {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 0%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 50% 50%;
    }
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

#wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

#left {
    flex: 0 0 65%;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 20%;
    animation: fadein 3s;
}

#right {
    flex: 1;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 20%;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    animation: fadein 6s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 6s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 6s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 6s;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="bg">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="left">1 div</div>
            <div id="right">2 div</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: background-image let you have several images, the first one takes precedence, and you can give each one its own position and size. See [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: i try using this css but seem not correct ->   background-image: linear-gradient(106deg,#313131 50%,white 50.1%),
                  url("bg.jpg");

Comment: It’s the wrong way round, the first one takes precedence.

Comment: how to make it exacts fit the div 2 white part, i try it will cover above the entire black part

Comment: You need to use background-size and position for  each image, please see my original comment and read [link] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your gradient black/transparent and put the image below it:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.bg {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(106deg, #313131 50%, transparent 50.1%),
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPLa1m.jpg) right;
  animation: BgAnimation 1.3s forwards;
  background-size: 200% 200%,80% auto;
}

@keyframes BgAnimation {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 0%,right;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 50% 50%,right;
  }
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  flex: 0 0 65%;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  animation: fadein 3s;
}

#right {
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  animation: fadein 6s;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="left">1 div</div>
      <div id="right">2 div</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```